# BigQuery row in Dataflow - "getF()" returns null

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

We have a Pipeline which reads from a BigQuery table. Calling the method `getF()` on the TableRow should return a `List<TableCell>` for that row. But it returns `null`.

Why does `getF()` return `null`?

```
@Override
public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
   TableRow aRow = context.element();
   List<TableCell> tableCells = aRow.getF(); //This returns null! 
}
```

Comment: Hey polleyg, taking a look at this behavior. Do you have a repro handy? (it's certainly unexpected)

Comment: Well, just take that code snippet and pull in any table in BigQuery, and you'll be able to repro.

Comment: We've identified the issue in how a TableRow is being constructed. Thanks PolleyG!

Comment: OK. Any idea when the fix will be rolled out?

Comment: Not yet, but I'll make sure I comment here when it's available in GitHub.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update from January 2016: `getF()` is not supported - support for it was never reliable and has been completely removed in [this commit](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/commit/6a11a72fd73a97fdc2c23f55c84696ce6e2a4e78). Please use `row.get("fieldname")` instead.

Original from September 2015: The SDK has been updated with a fix for this issue.

Comment: Update April 2021, this issue still persist.. I had wasted few hours investigating, and finally this link helped

Answer (score 2):

`getF()` is not supported - support for it was never reliable and has been completely removed in [this commit](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/commit/6a11a72fd73a97fdc2c23f55c84696ce6e2a4e78). Please use `row.get("fieldname")` instead.