# null TableCell when reading from BQ using dataflow

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I got null element when reading from BigQuery table using dataflow as follows

```
private static class ParseBQInput extends DoFn<TableRow, KV<String, MyClass> > {
    @Override
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
        TableRow row = c.element();
        List<TableCell> cells = row.getF();
        if (cells == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Get null cells");
        }

        // Other operation
    }
}
```

The cell I extracted with `row.getF()` is null regardless which table i read. 
I noticed that there is similar question already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30316173/bigquery-row-in-dataflow-getf-returns-null) but the answer is sort of unclear to me... I have tried updated the library version to 1.3.0 but it seems that the problem is still not solved. (Due to some dependency issue, it is a little painful to go to version 1.4.0 at current...)

(As a newbie to stack overflow, i don't have enough points to post comments though, so have to ask again here...)

Comment: I've updated the question you are linking to with http://stackoverflow.com/a/35326342/278042 .

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue?

Comment: @Nicholas hey using the `get("fieldname")` works for me. while never with `getF()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BigQuery row in Dataflow - "getF()" returns null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30316173/bigquery-row-in-dataflow-getf-returns-null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the updated https://stackoverflow.com/a/35326342/4392693, `getF()` will not be supported in newer versions.  Please use `get("fieldname")`.  Thank you for your patience.